# Get local Timezone and convert DB timing into it

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datetime

I am displaying time on Front-End and Time stored in DB is in CST form Example 23:35:00 . I am displaying it using PHP code below:

```
$formatedEventTime = "--";
 if($eventTime != ''){
 $formatedEventTime = date('h:i A', strtotime($eventTime));
}
//displays 11:35 PM
```

Now I need to get local time for people viewing it in New York or San Francisco and display them time in their local TimeZone
I am not sure what will be the best approach to do this as I can use :

```
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getTimezoneOffset();
var timezone = n / -60;
console.log(timezone);
```

Then I need to convert it into hours and perform addition / subtraction based on response. Is there a better approach to this?

```
<script> var localTimeZone = moment.tz.guess();
    //  console.log(localTimeZone);
  </script>
//as per comments I am using momentJS
```

I am able to print Local timeZone like America/Chicago how do I use it in my PHP and display time based on it ?

Comment: https://momentjs.com/ Take a look at this library, I think it will help you a lot.

Comment: Ok I used momentJS now I get the timezone as JS variable how do I convert it in php look at my updated question

Comment: If you want to use the timezone in your PHP you should send it to your PHP code using ajax. But why you wanna use PHP to display it when you can also use javascript to display it?

Answer (score -1):

JS holds the date in UTC, and will display it appropriate to the user's timezone on their device. So one way is to instantiate it with the eventTime in ms from epoch `(new Date($eventTime)).toLocaleString()` (pseudo code).

For anything with addition / subtraction etc, I recommend the [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) library